# idevicerestore fails to compile on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ubuntu, xubuntu, ios, iphone

Trying to compile idevicerestore, but it fails midway through.
Heres the log

```
libtoolize: linking file `./ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR, `m4'.
libtoolize: linking file `m4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: linking file `m4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: linking file `m4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: linking file `m4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: linking file `m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
libtoolize: Consider adding `-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
configure.ac:11: installing './compile'
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
/home/nikola/Desktop/idevicerestore/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/home/nikola/Desktop/idevicerestore/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for libimobiledevice... yes
checking for libplist... yes
checking for libzip... yes
checking for libcurl... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/nikola/Desktop/idevicerestore'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/nikola/Desktop/idevicerestore/src'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/p11-kit-1  -I/usr/include/libxml2  -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzip/include   -g -O2 -MT idevicerestore-idevicerestore.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/idevicerestore-idevicerestore.Tpo -c -o idevicerestore-idevicerestore.o `test -f 'idevicerestore.c' || echo './'`idevicerestore.c
idevicerestore.c: In function ‘main’:
idevicerestore.c:381:4: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    plist_dict_insert_item(info, "RestoreBehavior", plist_new_string((client->flags & FLAG_ERASE) ? "Erase" : "Update"));
    ^
idevicerestore.c:382:4: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    plist_dict_insert_item(info, "Variant", plist_new_string((client->flags & FLAG_ERASE) ? "Customer Erase Install (IPSW)" : "Customer Upgrade Install (IPSW)"));
    ^
idevicerestore.c:383:4: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    plist_dict_insert_item(build_identity, "Info", info);
    ^
idevicerestore.c:426:5: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     plist_dict_insert_item(info, "Path", plist_new_string(tmpstr));
     ^
idevicerestore.c:428:5: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     plist_dict_insert_item(comp, "Info", info);
     ^
idevicerestore.c:431:6: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      plist_dict_insert_item(manifest, compname, comp);
      ^
idevicerestore.c:433:7: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       plist_dict_insert_item(manifest, "RestoreDeviceTree", plist_copy(comp));
       ^
idevicerestore.c:446:4: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    plist_dict_insert_item(info, "Path", plist_new_string(tmpstr));
    ^
idevicerestore.c:448:4: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    plist_dict_insert_item(comp, "Info", info);
    ^
idevicerestore.c:449:4: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    plist_dict_insert_item(manifest, "iBSS", comp);
    ^
idevicerestore.c:454:4: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    plist_dict_insert_item(info, "Path", plist_new_string(tmpstr));
    ^
idevicerestore.c:456:4: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    plist_dict_insert_item(comp, "Info", info);
    ^
idevicerestore.c:457:4: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    plist_dict_insert_item(manifest, "iBEC", comp);
    ^
idevicerestore.c:470:7: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       plist_dict_insert_item(info, "Path", plist_copy(kc));
       ^
idevicerestore.c:472:7: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       plist_dict_insert_item(comp, "Info", info);
       ^
idevicerestore.c:473:7: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       plist_dict_insert_item(manifest, "KernelCache", comp);
       ^
idevicerestore.c:474:7: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       plist_dict_insert_item(manifest, "RestoreKernelCache", plist_copy(comp));
       ^
idevicerestore.c:486:6: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      plist_dict_insert_item(info, "Path", plist_copy(rd));
      ^
idevicerestore.c:488:6: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      plist_dict_insert_item(comp, "Info", info);
      ^
idevicerestore.c:489:6: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      plist_dict_insert_item(manifest, "RestoreRamDisk", comp);
      ^
idevicerestore.c:503:5: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     plist_dict_insert_item(info, "Path", plist_copy(os));
     ^
idevicerestore.c:505:5: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     plist_dict_insert_item(comp, "Info", info);
     ^
idevicerestore.c:506:5: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     plist_dict_insert_item(manifest, "OS", comp);
     ^
idevicerestore.c:510:4: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    plist_dict_insert_item(build_identity, "Manifest", manifest);
    ^
idevicerestore.c: In function ‘fixup_tss’:
idevicerestore.c:1108:4: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    plist_dict_insert_item(tss, "RestoreLogo", plist_copy(node2));
    ^
idevicerestore.c:1116:4: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    plist_dict_insert_item(tss, "RestoreDeviceTree", plist_copy(node2));
    ^
idevicerestore.c:1124:4: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    plist_dict_insert_item(tss, "RestoreKernelCache", plist_copy(node2));
    ^
mv -f .deps/idevicerestore-idevicerestore.Tpo .deps/idevicerestore-idevicerestore.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/p11-kit-1  -I/usr/include/libxml2  -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzip/include   -g -O2 -MT idevicerestore-common.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/idevicerestore-common.Tpo -c -o idevicerestore-common.o `test -f 'common.c' || echo './'`common.c
mv -f .deps/idevicerestore-common.Tpo .deps/idevicerestore-common.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/p11-kit-1  -I/usr/include/libxml2  -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzip/include   -g -O2 -MT idevicerestore-tss.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/idevicerestore-tss.Tpo -c -o idevicerestore-tss.o `test -f 'tss.c' || echo './'`tss.c
tss.c: In function ‘tss_create_request’:
tss.c:90:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(tss_request, "@APTicket", plist_new_bool(1));
  ^
tss.c:91:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(tss_request, "@BBTicket", plist_new_bool(1));
  ^
tss.c:92:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(tss_request, "@HostIpAddress", plist_new_string("192.168.0.1"));
  ^
tss.c:93:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(tss_request, "@HostPlatformInfo", plist_new_string("mac"));
  ^
tss.c:94:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(tss_request, "@Locality", plist_new_string("en_US"));
  ^
tss.c:97:3: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   plist_dict_insert_item(tss_request, "@UUID", plist_new_string(guid));
   ^
tss.c:100:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(tss_request, "@VersionInfo", plist_new_string("libauthinstall-107.3"));
  ^
tss.c:101:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(tss_request, "ApBoardID", plist_new_uint(board_id));
  ^
tss.c:102:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(tss_request, "ApChipID", plist_new_uint(chip_id));
  ^
tss.c:103:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(tss_request, "ApECID", plist_new_string(ecid_string));
  ^
tss.c:105:3: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   plist_dict_insert_item(tss_request, "ApNonce", plist_new_data(nonce, nonce_size));
   ^
tss.c:107:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(tss_request, "ApProductionMode", plist_new_bool(1));
  ^
tss.c:108:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(tss_request, "ApSecurityDomain", plist_new_uint(security_domain));
  ^
tss.c:109:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(tss_request, "UniqueBuildID", plist_new_data(unique_build_data, unique_build_size));
  ^
tss.c:140:3: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   plist_dict_insert_item(tss_request, key, tss_entry);
   ^
mv -f .deps/idevicerestore-tss.Tpo .deps/idevicerestore-tss.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/p11-kit-1  -I/usr/include/libxml2  -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzip/include   -g -O2 -MT idevicerestore-img3.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/idevicerestore-img3.Tpo -c -o idevicerestore-img3.o `test -f 'img3.c' || echo './'`img3.c
mv -f .deps/idevicerestore-img3.Tpo .deps/idevicerestore-img3.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/p11-kit-1  -I/usr/include/libxml2  -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzip/include   -g -O2 -MT idevicerestore-ipsw.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/idevicerestore-ipsw.Tpo -c -o idevicerestore-ipsw.o `test -f 'ipsw.c' || echo './'`ipsw.c
mv -f .deps/idevicerestore-ipsw.Tpo .deps/idevicerestore-ipsw.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/p11-kit-1  -I/usr/include/libxml2  -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzip/include   -g -O2 -MT idevicerestore-normal.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/idevicerestore-normal.Tpo -c -o idevicerestore-normal.o `test -f 'normal.c' || echo './'`normal.c
mv -f .deps/idevicerestore-normal.Tpo .deps/idevicerestore-normal.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/p11-kit-1  -I/usr/include/libxml2  -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzip/include   -g -O2 -MT idevicerestore-dfu.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/idevicerestore-dfu.Tpo -c -o idevicerestore-dfu.o `test -f 'dfu.c' || echo './'`dfu.c
mv -f .deps/idevicerestore-dfu.Tpo .deps/idevicerestore-dfu.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/p11-kit-1  -I/usr/include/libxml2  -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzip/include   -g -O2 -MT idevicerestore-recovery.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/idevicerestore-recovery.Tpo -c -o idevicerestore-recovery.o `test -f 'recovery.c' || echo './'`recovery.c
mv -f .deps/idevicerestore-recovery.Tpo .deps/idevicerestore-recovery.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/p11-kit-1  -I/usr/include/libxml2  -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzip/include   -g -O2 -MT idevicerestore-restore.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/idevicerestore-restore.Tpo -c -o idevicerestore-restore.o `test -f 'restore.c' || echo './'`restore.c
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:634:0,
                 from restore.c:24:
restore.c: In function ‘restore_device_callback’:
restore.c:185:30: error: ‘idevice_event_t’ has no member named ‘uuid’
   client->uuid = strdup(event->uuid);
                              ^
restore.c:185:30: error: ‘idevice_event_t’ has no member named ‘uuid’
   client->uuid = strdup(event->uuid);
                              ^
restore.c:185:30: error: ‘idevice_event_t’ has no member named ‘uuid’
   client->uuid = strdup(event->uuid);
                              ^
restore.c:185:30: error: ‘idevice_event_t’ has no member named ‘uuid’
   client->uuid = strdup(event->uuid);
                              ^
restore.c:185:30: error: ‘idevice_event_t’ has no member named ‘uuid’
   client->uuid = strdup(event->uuid);
                              ^
restore.c:185:30: error: ‘idevice_event_t’ has no member named ‘uuid’
   client->uuid = strdup(event->uuid);
                              ^
restore.c:185:30: error: ‘idevice_event_t’ has no member named ‘uuid’
   client->uuid = strdup(event->uuid);
                              ^
restore.c: In function ‘restore_send_root_ticket’:
restore.c:577:3: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   plist_dict_insert_item(dict, "RootTicketData", plist_new_data(data, (uint64_t)len));
   ^
restore.c: In function ‘restore_send_kernelcache’:
restore.c:626:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(dict, "KernelCacheFile", blob);
  ^
restore.c: In function ‘restore_send_nor’:
restore.c:700:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(dict, "LlbImageData", plist_new_data(llb_data, (uint64_t) llb_size));
  ^
restore.c:724:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(dict, "NorImageData", norimage_array);
  ^
restore.c: In function ‘restore_device’:
restore.c:821:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(opts, "AutoBootDelay", plist_new_uint(0));
  ^
restore.c:823:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(opts, "BootImageType", plist_new_string("UserOrInternal"));
  ^
restore.c:826:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(opts, "CreateFilesystemPartitions", plist_new_bool(1));
  ^
restore.c:827:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(opts, "DFUFileType", plist_new_string("RELEASE"));
  ^
restore.c:828:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(opts, "DataImage", plist_new_bool(0));
  ^
restore.c:831:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(opts, "FirmwareDirectory", plist_new_string("."));
  ^
restore.c:833:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(opts, "FlashNOR", plist_new_bool(1));
  ^
restore.c:837:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(opts, "KernelCacheType", plist_new_string("Release"));
  ^
restore.c:841:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(opts, "NORImageType", plist_new_string("production"));
  ^
restore.c:845:3: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   plist_dict_insert_item(opts, "RestoreBootArgs", plist_new_string(client->restore_boot_args));
   ^
restore.c:847:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(opts, "RestoreBundlePath", plist_new_string("/tmp/Per2.tmp"));
  ^
restore.c:848:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(opts, "RootToInstall", plist_new_bool(0));
  ^
restore.c:851:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(opts, "SystemImage", plist_new_bool(1));
  ^
restore.c:854:3: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   plist_dict_insert_item(spp, "16", plist_new_uint(160));
   ^
restore.c:855:3: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   plist_dict_insert_item(spp, "32", plist_new_uint(320));
   ^
restore.c:856:3: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   plist_dict_insert_item(spp, "64", plist_new_uint(640));
   ^
restore.c:857:3: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   plist_dict_insert_item(spp, "8", plist_new_uint(80));
   ^
restore.c:860:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(opts, "SystemImageType", plist_new_string("User"));
  ^
restore.c:862:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(opts, "SystemPartitionPadding", spp);
  ^
restore.c:865:3: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   plist_dict_insert_item(opts, "UUID", plist_new_string(guid));
   ^
restore.c:869:2: warning: ‘plist_dict_insert_item’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/plist/plist.h:339): use plist_dict_set_item instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  plist_dict_insert_item(opts, "UpdateBaseband", plist_new_bool(0));
  ^
restore.c:874:18: error: too few arguments to function ‘restored_start_restore’
  restore_error = restored_start_restore(restore);
                  ^
In file included from restore.c:25:0:
/usr/include/libimobiledevice/restore.h:64:18: note: declared here
 restored_error_t restored_start_restore(restored_client_t client, plist_t options, uint64_t version);
                  ^
Makefile:574: recipe for target 'idevicerestore-restore.o' failed
make[2]: *** [idevicerestore-restore.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nikola/Desktop/idevicerestore/src'
Makefile:402: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nikola/Desktop/idevicerestore'
Makefile:333: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I had to shorten the log because it was way too big!
Hopefully this is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem with Slackware Current.

Because **libimobiledevice** version **1.2.0** has change *restored_start_restore* function definition

```
restored_error_t restored_start_restore (   restored_client_t   client,
    plist_t     options,
    uint64_t    version 
)
```

but in **idevicerestore** use only one parameter

```
restored_start_restore(restore);
```

I change the line with error in this way like https://github.com/tcf38012/idevicerestore/commit/ced8086ab331f4960e7d1eb651d51d96e08caf90

Before

```
 restore_error = restored_start_restore(restore);
```

After

```
restore_error = restored_start_restore(restore, opts, client->restore->protocol_version);
```

Then the error disappear, but there are also other error.

changing also

```
event->uuid
```

with

```
event->udid
```

compilation work fine, but I must also test if program works good.

This is the patch for the file **src/restore.c**

```
--- ../idevicerestore/src/restore.c 2015-10-21 10:53:16.981124442 +0200
+++ src/restore.c   2015-10-21 11:19:51.331167137 +0200
@@ -182,7 +182,7 @@
    struct idevicerestore_client_t* client = (struct idevicerestore_client_t*) userdata;
    if (event->event == IDEVICE_DEVICE_ADD) {
        restore_device_connected = 1;
-       client->uuid = strdup(event->uuid);
+       client->uuid = strdup(event->udid);
    } else if (event->event == IDEVICE_DEVICE_REMOVE) {
        restore_device_connected = 0;
        client->flags |= FLAG_QUIT;
@@ -871,7 +871,7 @@
    //plist_dict_insert_item(opts, "UserLocale", plist_new_string("en_US"));

    // start the restore process
-   restore_error = restored_start_restore(restore);
+   restore_error = restored_start_restore(restore, opts, client->restore->protocol_version);
    if (restore_error != RESTORE_E_SUCCESS) {
        error("ERROR: Unable to start the restore process\n");
        plist_free(opts);
```